# How to fill a meteor collection with graphics and individually display them

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, meteor

I am trying to add a feature that allows me to drag little graphics (think 20x20px) around a web page. There should be a list with all the icons and via clicking them and double-clicking the page background, copies can be generated on the page that are draggable.

The dragging is done via jquery-ui and works. Now I am wondering how to get the images into the collection.

What I want to do is have one collection to conveniently display all the available icons, and another one to handle the ones that are being worked with.

Here is the template for the latter:

```
<template name="usedIcon">
<div draggable="true" class="draggableImageDiv" id="{{_id}}" style="position:absolute;left:{{left}};top:{{top}};">
    <img src="{{imagePath}}" class="draggableImage" alt="test-image" />
</div>
```

This works for a set image path. But now I intend to make an event handler for the availableIcon class that sets the image path in a certain variable upon clicking and then allows that variable to be used to insert a new object with the particular imagepath in the usedIcons collection.

For that I need to first insert the paths into the availableIcons collection

Is there a convenient way to populate the availableIcons collection with the imagePath variables? I was thinking doing it manually in a startup function, which isn't very elegant. CollectionsFS can probably do this better and also make this more elegant than using the paths but I don't have any Idea how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [CollectionFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs) package available for meteor. You'll need the cfs:standard-packages too, but gridfs allows you to easily put all the images in a collection and get a URL for them.

Hope that helps.